# Hive on OS X EL Capitan: Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set

Tags: macos, hadoop, path, hive, bigdata

I'm trying to start **Hive 2.1.1** on my OSX EL Capitan:

I have pre installed and working **Hadoop-2.7.3**

Also my .bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/dev/hadoop-2.7.3
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin/

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

export HIVE_HOME=/Users/dev/apache-hive-2.1.1
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/dev/hadoop-2.7.3/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/dev/apache-hive-2.1.1/lib/*:.
```

Also I added to ~/apache-location/bin/hive-config.sh following line:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/Users/dev/hadoop-2.7.3
```

But when I try

```
$ bin/hive
```

I still have following problem:
Cannot find hadoop installation: 
`$HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path`

I have already put same exports in:

```
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
```

But it does not help..
What have I missed? Any ideas?